# What's the movie about two brothers with their health being predicted by a device as soon as they were born?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I guess, the movie is set in the future, because we have no such devices yet. When a child is born, a doctor makes a pinch in a child's foot with a device that predicts the child's health.

There were two brothers. The device indicated one would be healthy, one would not. I don't remember whether the device predicted success or just health.

Their daddy loved the healthy child, the other was neglected.

As the story goes one, the poor kid actually becomes more physically fit and successful than his brother. The movie ends with the neglected kid going to space.

I watched this movie a long time ago and now want to watch it again. I don't remember the title. I tried Googling, but had no success.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe that you are thinking of Gattaca. It presents a society driven by eugenics. A family has two sons, one "naturally" and one using the genetic manipulations. The natural born son faces much discrimination because of his poor genetics. Eventually, he borrows the identity of a "valid" (since genetically he is unfit for the space program) who has an exceptional genetic print but who suffered a car accident and is now paraplegic. Eventually, this son makes onto a space mission. You can find out more at [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119177/) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattaca).

Comment: Yea, that's the movie. Seems like I got some details wrong, but anyway. Thank you very much! :)